# Xampp/ Lampp Mysql access

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, ubuntu-16.04

I install on Ubuntu 16.04 LTE Xampp (lampp) all good It Works:

```
:~$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.20-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...already running.

:~$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp status
Version: XAMPP for Linux 5.6.20-0
Apache is running.
MySQL is not running.
ProFTPD is running.

:~$ sudo service mysql start

:~$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp status
Version: XAMPP for Linux 5.6.20-0
Apache is running.
MySQL is not running.
ProFTPD is running.
```

But when I want to enter the TERMINAL has mysql -u root:

> ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

And if i use sudo mysql -u root, all is ok I can use mysql by terminal.

But for Firefox http://127.0.01/phpmyadmin/ :

```
Welcome to phpMyAdmin

Error

MySQL said: Documentation
Cannot connect: invalid settings.
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check the permissions under  /var/lib  and  /var/run
I had a similar situation and solved by changing the permission on those folders then run 
$./etc/init.d/mysql start